# Lottery permutations

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

This lottery game has a ticket where you choose 5 different numbers from 1 to 75, inclusive, in the pink part of the ticket. Then you choose one number from 1 to 15 , inclusive, from the white part of the ticket. Determine the total number of different possible selections of numbers that could be made.'

My attempt:
I assume here that order is important,so use permutations, so that, 75P5 * 15P1 to give 2,071,126,800 * 15 = 31,066,902,000.
Is that correct, or does it use combinations?

Comment: Do the same with a lottery where you choose $2$ different numbers from $1$ to $3$ in the pink part and one number from $1$ to $2$ from the white part. This to sharpen your understanding.

Comment: I don't know what country you're in, but in typical lottery draws the order is **not** important.

Answer (score 2):

See its combination permutations make arrangements while combinations make selection. So here we want selection of tickets thus its combination so total ways are ${75\choose 5}.{15\choose 1}$ hope its clear now.